# Elements not positionable on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a Fragment element, but I can't position widget anywhere - it's just fixed on the top-left angle.

[image]

[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="layout.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="259dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar4" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Why this problem? This is my first Android application, but when using a normal Activity, the position works.

Comment: Can you share your xml

Comment: Yes,  posted XML =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `android:layout_gravity`. For example, if you want to center it:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar5" />
```

You are using `FrameLayout` which stacks children on top of other. If this is not what you want, consider using `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.